# Regular expression for incoming data from serial port

Tags: regex

I have a data format coming from **serial port** as followinng :

```
4.99,2.34,25300\n
```

The application will be able to detect **termination character (\n).** The problem is I need to parse the message to extract each number.

Comment: It seems that the  `,` is the number separator, am I right? Can't you just use the `String.Split` method?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion, does it work for you? Or do you really need to use a regex?

Comment: I do need it in regular expression if possible

Comment: Added another answer with regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using String.Split instead of regular expressions:

```
string data = @"4.99,2.34,25300\n";

List<double> numbers = data.Replace(@"\n", String.Empty)
                           .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                           .Select(x => double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it to be done in regular expression. Thanks again for your response

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

```
string regex = @"(\d+(\.\d+)?),?";
string data = @"4.99,2.34,25300\n";

IEnumerable<double> numbers = from match in Regex.Matches(data, regex)
                              let number = match.Groups[1].Value
                              select double.Parse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

foreach (double number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

I am using parentesis to [capture substrings within a match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions).

The first match `4.99,`, as you can see from the screenshot has 3 groups:

- the 1st group (index 0) matches everything: `4.99,`
- the 2nd group (index 1) matches the number `4.99` - this is what we want
- the 3rd group matches the `,`

[image: Regular expression match groups]